# How to prevent a landscape page from turning upside down when printed?

Tags: pdf, landscape, printing

I have some problems when I want to print a PDF where one of the pages has been turned to landscape format.

In the PDF, I turned one page to landscape format to make it easier to read an image (note that the image is facing outwards in `twoside` mode). On the PDF viewer I get the following result which is as I expected:
[image]

However, when I print the document, the page is printed upside down and I get this:
[image]

I would like the page to be printed right side up and get the following result:
[image]

I don't know if it's my printer that's set up wrong, but is it possible to fix this problem? I don't know how the PDF format works, but is it possible to indicate in the PDF the direction in which to print the pages in landscape format?

Here is a MWE (part of the code comes from: [How to make landscape mode rotate properly in a twoside book?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982219/how-to-make-landscape-mode-rotate-properly-in-a-twoside-book)):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe, pdflscape, lipsum}

\makeatletter % From : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982219/how-to-make-landscape-mode-rotate-properly-in-a-twoside-book
\global\let\orig@begin@landscape=\landscape%
\global\let\orig@end@landscape=\endlandscape%
\gdef\@true{1}
\gdef\@false{0}
\gdef\landscape{%
    \global\let\within@landscape=\@true%
    \orig@begin@landscape%
}%
\gdef\endlandscape{%
    \orig@end@landscape%
    \global\let\within@landscape=\@false%
}%
\@ifpackageloaded{pdflscape}{%
    \gdef\pdf@landscape@rotate{\PLS@Rotate}%
}{
    \gdef\pdf@landscape@rotate#1{}%
}
\let\latex@outputpage\@outputpage
\def\@outputpage{
    \ifx\within@landscape\@true%
        \if@twoside%
            \ifodd\c@page%
                \gdef\LS@rot{\setbox\@outputbox\vbox{%
                    \pdf@landscape@rotate{-90}%
                    \hbox{\rotatebox{90}{\hbox{\rotatebox{180}{\box\@outputbox}}}}}%
                }%
            \else%
                \gdef\LS@rot{\setbox\@outputbox\vbox{%
                    \pdf@landscape@rotate{+90}%
                    \hbox{\rotatebox{90}{\hbox{\rotatebox{0}{\box\@outputbox}}}}}%
                }%
            \fi%
        \else%
            \gdef\LS@rot{\setbox\@outputbox\vbox{%
                \pdf@landscape@rotate{+90}%
                \hbox{\rotatebox{90}{\hbox{\rotatebox{0}{\box\@outputbox}}}}}%
            }%
        \fi%
    \fi%
    \latex@outputpage%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\section{My section}

\lipsum[1-12]

\begin{landscape}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{landscape}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: pdflscape takes care of the pdf rotation. That is its main point. So remove all your patches and try again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. I used this patch to make the figures always face outward in twoside mode, because it's easier to read. Isn't it possible to combine the best of both worlds?

Comment: I believe that this outside of the scope of LaTeX. I may be wrong, but I think that the PDF does not "know" that that page has been rotated; it just knows that it has a different size. That the page is rotated for printing at all is a feature of your PDF viewer which assumes that pages are rotated clockwise. I don't know if there are any PDF viewers out there that try to detect pages that are rotated the other way by analizing their content.

Comment: As a side note, I'm not convinced that it is easier to read those pages this way. When there is a double page with two rotated images, I'd want both of them to be rotated the same way.

Comment: Following logic, it would make sense for the bottom of the rotated image to point in the "forward" direction, that is to the right of the page in an L-to-R document.  Although it may be tempting to turn it to always face the outside, consider the effect if two landscape tables on facing pages were actually two parts of the same table -- confusion.

Comment: I am confused. If you turn the first figure left side paper 180 degree, it will be exact same as the second figure left side figure. So the layout of the material is printed as your expectation. What is wrong here?

Comment: Hello @Tom, the problem is that if I print a double-sided document, then the front of the page is printed in the right direction while the back (if the page is turned as in my example) is printed in the wrong direction. Turning the page will make the front side upside down and the back side right side up.

Comment: Hello @schtandard, I'm also afraid this is not a Latex problem. You are right if two rotated pages follow each other, but in my document there are few rotated pages and they never follow each other.

Comment: @Bastien I see right now. If this is for a thesis, maybe use oneside printing instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The landscape environement of the lscape package is meant for longer text and so it rotates always counter clockwise.
With your code you are trying to change this but this create an up-side-down page, and so the printer is doing the right thing.

If you want alternating rotations, sidewaysfigure from the rotating package is normally better (but I agree with the comments that it is much more agreable to read if images always rotate to the same side, as one then has to turn the book only in one direction). You can then set the rotation in the pdf viewer with the commands from the new pdfmanagement (this requires a current latex!)

```
\DocumentMetadata{} %load pdfmanagement
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\section{My section}

\lipsum[1-12]

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\label{fig:1}
\int_if_odd:nTF {\getpagerefnumber{fig:1}}
 {\pdfmanagement_add:nnn {ThisPage} {Rotate} {90}}
 {\pdfmanagement_add:nnn {ThisPage} {Rotate} {-90}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{sidewaysfigure}


\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\label{fig:2}
\int_if_odd:nTF {\getpagerefnumber{fig:2}}
 {\pdfmanagement_add:nnn {ThisPage} {Rotate} {90}}
 {\pdfmanagement_add:nnn {ThisPage} {Rotate} {-90}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ulrike Fischer, thank you for your reply, but when I print the document, the even-numbered pages are always printed upside down. As @schtandard said in the comments, maybe the problem cannot be solved via Latex?